# Maths challenge question: Is my reasoning behind this question correct?

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Problem:
(From Hamilton Maths Olympiad 2015)

> Some boys and girls are standing in a row, in some order, about to be photographed. All of them are facing the photographer. Each girl counts the number of boys to her left, and each boy counts the number of girls to his right.
>
> Let the sum of the numbers counted by the girls be $G$, and the sum of the numbers counted by the boys be $B$.
>
> Prove that $G = B$.

My Proof:

> Let's say we have the example: $gbbgggbbgbb$.
>
> We can visualise the solution using the above. With my example, I am going to add two bins to each side. This makes:
> $$\_ \, g\, b\, b\, g\, g\, g\, b\, b\, g\, b\, b\, \_$$
> Let's first count boys to the left as we move along each girl.
>
> Each string of boys or girls are either named $g_n$ or $b_n$.
>
> 1. As we move along each girl, we get:
>    $$g_1 \times b_1 + g_2(b_1 + b_2) + g_3(b_1 + b_2 + b_3) \ldots g_r(b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + \ldots b_r)$$
> 2. As we move along each boy we get:
>    $$b_1 \times g_1 + b_2(g_1 + g_2) + b_3(g_1 + g_2 + g_3) \ldots b_r(g_1 + g_2 + g_3 \ldots g_r)$$
>
> For the girls we can write this sum out as:
> $$\begin{matrix}
> g_1 & & & & & & \color{teal}{b_1} \\
> g_1 & g_2 & & & & & \color{teal}{b_2} \\
> g_1 & g_2 & g_3 & & & & \color{teal}{b_3} \\
> g_1 & g_2 & g_3 & g_4 & & & \color{teal}{b_4} \\
> \vdots & & & & & & \color{teal}{\vdots} \\
> g_1 & g_2 & g_3 & g_4 & \cdots & g_r & \color{teal}{b_r}
> \end{matrix}$$
> Let's do the same for the boys:
> $$\begin{matrix}
> b_1 & & & & & & \color{teal}{g_1} \\
> b_1 & b_2 & & & & & \color{teal}{g_2} \\
> b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & & & & \color{teal}{g_3} \\
> b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & & & \color{teal}{g_4} \\
> \vdots & & & & & & \color{teal}{\vdots} \\
> b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & \cdots & b_r & \color{teal}{g_r}
> \end{matrix}$$
> Then take the diagonals of each diagram:
> \begin{align}
> &b_1 \times \color{teal}{g_1} + b_2 \times \color{teal}{g_2} + b_3 \times \color{teal}{g_3} + b_4 \times \color{teal}{g_4} + \ldots + b_r \times g_r \\
> = \, &\color{teal}{g_1} \times b_1 + \color{teal}{g_2} \times b_2 + \color{teal}{g_3} \times b_3 + \color{teal}{g_4} \times b_4 + \ldots + \color{teal}{g_r} \times b_r
> \end{align}
> The above are both equal, so all other matching diagonals must be equal.
>
> Therefore $G = B$

[Editor's note: this was copied verbatim from the original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owORG.jpg).]

I have answered this maths challenge problem.

The official solution is a lot less convoluted than mine, but I was wondering if I managed a full proof solution, or if there are any errors that I haven't noticed. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It is generally frowned upon to rely on pictures where text would suffice, so I have formatted your question and answer using MathJax, the mark up language we use to format mathematics (it's basically Latex, if you're familiar with it). We have a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for learning how to use it, and you can also click [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4748707/edit) to see how I've formatted your post. I recommend playing around with it, without pressing submit, to see how it all works.

Comment: Also, as part of our [policy on contest questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy), we require you to mention which contest this came from, to verify the contest is not currently active (which, by the sounds of it, the contest is over). Otherwise, your question may be down-voted (further) and closed.

Comment: Why do you say all the diagonals of each diagram are equal ? If you look at the second diagonal of the first diagram you get $g_1b_2+g_2b_3+\ldots+g_{r-1}b_r$ which is different from what you get by looking at the second diagonal of the second diagram, that is, $b_1g_2+b_2g_3+\ldots+b_{r-1}g_r$.

Comment: @Angelo Oh yes. Is there any way to group of count items for the sums of girls and boys to show they are equal? Or is this approach fundamentally flawed? Why, though, it seems to make sense to me? Thanks for any help.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you for taking the time to format and copy out my image. I'll make sure to look more closely at the rules next time.

Comment: You add an extra "bin" on either end -- why? It seems you never mention these bins again. You say $g_1$ is the name of a string of girls, but then you use it in multiplication and addition; is it the _number_ of girls in a string? First string on the left, first string on the right, something else? Why do you assume the number of strings of girls and boys is the same? How did you come up with the sums in paragraphs 1. and 2.? The symmetry of those sums looks wrong; do these really represent girls counting boys on their **left** and boys counting girls on their **right**?

Comment: Now that your attempted proof has been written into the question rather than shown only in a picture, it should be easy enough for you to edit it further to supply the parts you were thinking but forgot to write down.

Comment: @Manike351 The contest problem rules are not particularly easy to find, so I understand missing them. You can still edit your question and add in some basic information about the contest: which contest, in which year is all that's necessary.

Comment: @TheoBendit It looks like that information was already given about 3 hours ago.